# List of recently added Facebook friends?

Tags: facebook, friends

Is there a way to see what friends I recently added? It used to be possible using "Edit friends" but this part has changed it seems.

"Became friends with" stories are set to not appear on my wall.

It seems to possible be [using the API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8876413) but is there an easier way?

Comment: If you have timeline, there's a box on the right side that shows the most recent additions.

Comment: @dnbrv But not *all* your recent additions. And the first answer method do it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Go to your activity log (`https://www.facebook.com/<yourusername>/allactivity`) and filter by friends.

Direct link: `https://www.facebook.com/<yourusername>/allactivity?privacy_source=activity_log&log_filter=cluster_8`

Comment: Or (especially if you don't have a username) go to your Timeline and click on Activity Log and filter by friends.  (If you don't have Timeline yet then neither will work.)

Comment: Thanks! I will try this when I get switched to Timeline.

Comment: Thanks so much! Am really grateful there's still an approach for this. Am surprised the new search bar doesn't allow for "my recently added friends"

Comment: this no longer works in 2018

Comment: @jsky I just checked, it works.

Comment: my mistake, so it does, i misinterpreted what you meant by filter.

Answer (score 2):

Try this link:

https://www.facebook.com/YOURNAME/timeline/2015/12

one of the sections should appear like so:

[image: My New Friends acquired in December]

(for November change the 12 in the link to 11, etc.)

Comment: I have zero section on the left side... maybe because of my FB settings? http://i.imgur.com/HE6qSfI.png

Answer (score 1):

Try going to Account Settings > Notifications. It shows all of your recent activity, which includes added friends.

Comment: It does not include friends I accepted (only "accepted your friend request"). It seems to include one week of information, not sure if exhaustive though.

Comment: That one week thing is funny, because I was with a friend the other day and their info extended back like a month.. no idea how.

Answer (score 0):

```
https://www.facebook.com/{your username}/allactivity?privacy_source=activity_log_top_menu
```

newest link if anyone out there is curious!